# Calculate percentage average of column of values that match specific text criteria in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How can I calculate the average percentages in the screenshot below? I've tried a number of different formulas such as:

- sumif/countif
- average(if)
- averageif
- averageifs
- arrayformula(average....)

But I get, Error:

> ## Div/0, #value or wrong results

I would appreciate your help. I'm using the latest google spreadsheets available. See below the table.

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16GxPXdTEte1lDYWt8RyJPdAI3eLRayHZA1cP5vPmfmQ/edit#gid=0)

Or see below:

[image: Spreadsheet Data]

What's the average Bounce Rate of all the pages that **contain** "intl-en-gb"?

Bounce Rate=?

What's the average Bounce Rate of the pages that **exactly match** "intl-en-gb"?

Bounce Rate=?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I got your comment right but I'm looking for a formula that would calculate average and exclude anything including "-%" within the column.

Comment: That works indeed! thanks for that. Do you have any ideas for my first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example spreadsheet of Database functions:

[Example Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0As3tAuweYU9QdEVHdTFHNzloSTY4LVYxdW9LdHRHbEE&mode=public&ddrp=1#)

To exclude zero values, use a second criteria with DAverage.  The criteria
are designated in a range of cells with column titles.

[image: Daverage Usage]

Range A19:B20 is the criteria definition.  The formula is:

> =DAVERAGE(A6:B16,"Bounce Rate",A19:B20)

Note that this is matching everything that has "/intl/en-gb/" anywhere in the string, not just a perfect match.